# C memcpy 2D array to 3D array within function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, memcpy

In the example below, I have a 3D array which I pass to a function, "fun", but only pass a "slice" of the 3D array i.e. a 2D array. Within the function, I have another 2D variable, which takes on some values within a double for loop. Before exiting the function, I need to copy the 2D temporary array to the "slice" of the 3D array. I tried the following, but my use of memcpy is "destroying" the original 3D array outside the function. What is the proper way to perform this operation?

```
void fun(double **array, int XDIM, int YDIM);   // Declaration

int main()
{
    double ***array
    int XDIM=10,YDIM=10,TDIM=2;

    allocate3d(&array,XDIM,YDIM,TDIM); // This works fine
    fun(array[0],XDIM,YDIM);

    //
    //  Other code note important to problem here
    //

    deallocate3d(array,XDIM,YDIM,TDIM); // This works fine
}


void fun(double **array, int XDIM, int YDIM)
{
    double **tmp;

    allocate2d(&tmp,XDIM,YDIM); // This works fine

    for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < XDIM; i++)
        {
            tmp[j][i] = 2.5;
        }
    }

    memcpy(array,tmp,XDIM*YDIM*sizeof(double));

    deallocate2d(tmp,XDIM,YDIM); // This works fine

}
```

EDIT: I want to add that "array" has dimensions of

```
array[TDIM][YDIM][XDIM]
```

and "tmp" has dimensions of

```
tmp[YDIM][XDIM]
```

I did address this in a comment, but thought I should point it out in the main question. I also showed that I free the memory of tmp within the function.

EDIT 2: I'm including the "allocate3D" and "deallocate3D" functions for further analysis of memory storage.

```
int allocate3D(double ****array, int XDIM, int YDIM, int TDIM)
{
    // Allocate 3rd dimension
    *array = calloc(TDIM,sizeof(double**));
    if (array==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in memory allocation\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate each 3rd dimensional pointer with array of pointers
    for(int i = 0; i < TDIM; i++)
    {
        (*array)[i] = calloc(YDIM,sizeof(double*));
    }

    if (array==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in memory allocation\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate remaining dimension
    for(int i = 0; i < TDIM; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
        {
            (*array)[i][j] = calloc(XDIM,sizeof(double));
        }
    }

    if(array == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in memory allocation\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
void deallocate3D(double ***array, int XDIM, int YDIM, int TDIM)
{
    //  Deallocate each 3rd dimensional pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < TDIM; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
        {
            free((array)[i][j]);
        }

        free((array)[i]);
    }

    // Deallocate 3rd dimension
    free(array);
}
```

The functions "allocate2D" and "deallocate2D" follow the same concept, minus the "TDIM" dimension, so I will leave it out for the sake of simplicity. It has been brought to my attention that the portion of the array which I'm trying to use with "memcpy" may not be contiguous and is "jagged". In addition to providing the allocation function, is there a simple way to identify contiguous memory storage? How do 3D arrays get stored in memory?

EDIT 3: I think I may have found a clue...in the example above, I'm setting YDIM == 1. I believe this affects the contiguous memory alignment and my allocation and free functions are causing errors. I've used Valgrind and it flags my allocation and free functions when YDIM == 1. In addition, this would affect how memcpy is behaving. Any thoughts on my speculations? Why set YDIM == 1....cause sometimes that is the case. I'm trying to keep things universal in application.

Comment: Why you never use `free`? did you know it exists?

Comment: What does 'destroying' mean? Can you show us the code that inspects the return value and shows it to be 'destroyed'? I notice you've used your coordinates X, Y & T in a slightly inconsistent order so you may be scanning when you think you're slicing.

Comment: @ iharob I do....are implying that's why?

Comment: @ Dan when I exit the function and return to main, "array"'s memory is gone. I added this to the double for loop in the function: array[j][i] = tmp[i][j] and it works fine, but really I don't need the double for loop at all, hence why i was trying to use memcpy. (I'm using the debugger in eclipse)

Comment: @ Dan All of my operations are on a large X Y matrix. The time dimension (T), only stores the previous matrix. When I said "slice", I was referring to a "slice" of time. I'm currently storing them in memory as array[T][Y][X]. Are you saying it should be array[Y][X][T] or something diff?

Comment: `memcpy(array,tmp,XDIM*YDIM*sizeof(double));` Probably, You do not secure the liner array.(you have jagged array.)

Comment: To get better help, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe how the actual output differs from the expected output

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  the accepted solution should also be credited to you...I believe it is due to the "jagged" array. I didn't know what that was to begin with. Matt suggested that each allocation will pull a new block of memory, making it non contiguous thus "memcpy" wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to do in `fun` is:

```
for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < XDIM; i++)
    {
        array[j][i] = tmp[j][i];
    }
}
```

You cannot use a single `memcpy` because your array is not a contiguous bloc of memory; it is a *jagged array* (each 1-dimensional block is stored in a separate allocation).

I'm assuming you have your dimensions in the right order (you didn't post the body of `allocate3d` so that can't be verified)

Comment: Ahh, OK. I was wondering what BLUEPIXY was referring to when he said "jagged" array. I will add my allocate3d() function to the original code for further input. I know the allocation works, but I'm not quite clear on how the memory is aligned internally (as far as being contiguous). Would you mind looking at my function and commenting on the memory structure of the 3D array. Thanks!

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Each time you call `malloc` it allocates a separate chunk of memory. The term "jagged array" traditionally means an array whose rows are not of all the same length; but we can also use the same term for an array where each row is in a separate allocation even if the rows are all the same length.  Contiguous arrays (i.e. a single memory block) have to have all rows the same length.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I could do it the way you suggest, but in the end, I want to remove as many of these loops as possible and use functions like "memcpy". I believe they're much faster....correct me if I'm wrong.  I'll switch back to 1D arrays and contiguous allocations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need a temp array there. Since you're already passing in the array itself, and in c you can modify arrays directly with other functions. Maybe...

```
void fun(double **array, int XDIM, int YDIM)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < XDIM; i++)
        {
            array[j][i] = 2.5;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I don't think this is the problem, I might be wrong of course.

Comment: I only used the code above as a prototype...really tmp is a whole lot over other stuff and is case dependent, but in the end it's a 2D array.

Comment: I will add that you're code is right...but not what I'm after. Thanks though.